# Including Jabra Library in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm including a Jabra javascript library to my chrome extension project.

https://github.com/gnaudio/jabra-browser-integration/blob/master/README.md

This library talks to a chrome extension that needs to be installed coupled with a client thats installed on the windows pc.

If I run any of the github tools; for example https://gnaudio.github.io/jabra-browser-integration/release/test/ I have no problem seeing events.

If I create a small app and host it on Apache I can access the API no problem and see events.

When I run the app within my chrome extension it's not able to see the chrome extension and advises me to install it.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jabra-browser-integration/okpeabepajdgiepelmhkfhkjlhhmofma

[image: jabra_error]

On my chrome extension app I have tried including the javascript api library from my web host: `<script src="https://example.com/jabra_research/jabra.browser.integration-2.0.js"></script>`

Also please see my manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "Jabra",
    "manifest_version": 2,    
    "version": "0.3.9.2",
    "author": "Joe Bloggs",
    "description": "Get Jabra Headset Info",
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html",
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "ext_icons/icon_19.png",
            "38": "ext_icons/icon_38.png"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "ext_icons/icon_16.png",
        "48": "ext_icons/icon_48.png",
        "128": "ext_icons/icon_128.png"
    },
    "options_page": "config.html",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "alarms",
        "background",
        "tabs",
        "system.cpu",
        "contextMenus",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "notifications",
        "cookies",
        "*://*/*",
        "<all_urls>",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/",
        "management"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com/jabra_research/jabra.browser.integration-2.0.js; object-src 'self' https://example.com/jabra_research/jabra.browser.integration-2.0.js",

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "*"
    ]
}
```

My background.html file includes the API file. Its almost like when background.html runs it not being treated the same as normal chrome browser tab.

Is there anything one can recommend to try?

I noticed on the API at line 1080 'Only works if hosted under https'. I suspect this is something to do with it.

KR,
Aiden

Comment: Hello, have you solved this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Hi Durko, no unfortunately not. I have parked it for now to see if there is going to be any updates to facilitate this. Don't suppose you made any traction yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the script in the local folder structure (like a scripts folder) for your extension, so it ships with the tool and then update your manifest to include it as a background script so the functions in the script are available to to the background page and functions...

```
 "web_accessible_resources": [
        "*"
    ],
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js", "scripts/jabra.browser.integration-2.0.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

or inject script from your content script, injecting it into the head of your background html page...

```
//load scripts, 2 shown for usage clarification...
        var scripts = ["jabra_research/jabra.browser.integration-2.0.js"];

        function load_latest_script() {

            for (index = 0; index < scripts.length; ++index) {

                var script = document.createElement('script');

                //where my_url is your domain...
                script.src = my_url + scripts[index] 

                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                var done = false;

                //if all scripts are loaded then load stuff
                if (index == scripts.length-1) {
                    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
                            done = true;
                            //call a function in panel.js
                            load_stuff();
                        }
                    };
                }
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
            }
        }

        load_latest_script();
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Tried this to no avail. Same result. I can access the scripts functions ok, but when I try running jabra.init(); it fails. (the script will look to see if the jabra chrome extension is installed and thats where its failing) I noticed in the jabra chrome extension it listens to window events.

Comment: ... [https://github.com/gnaudio/jabra-browser-integration/blob/130ccd01271ff9ac9f6a639a7d581bf209481723/src/ChromeWebExtension/content-script.js#L65] .So when we load jabra.browser.intergration-2.0.js the content-script should fire, but doesn't within my own chrome-extension environment?

Comment: Answer updated.  Try to inject script from your content script into your html page.  That bit of code can inject X number of scripts.  Optionally tack a date time or guid to the script ("script.js?ver=123) to update any changes in the script so users don't have to re-install the extn when you make changes to the script.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Unfortunately Same error. Loaded file with inject function. Script loads in ok, can access its functions but same error while trying to fire jabra.init(); See pic that's added to question above showing this. The way that the Jabra Chrome Extension listens to window events for 'jabra-headset-extension-from-content-script' which i see in line 311 of jabra.browser.integration-2.0.js has something to do with it. does that give you a clue? Many Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the script is loaded as per that pic; however the error looks like it can't communicate with the jabra software on the machine.  I suspect you installed the local client as per the github instructions and have a the appropriate headset? I would try there chrome extension, perhaps the older .5 version and see if that works, else enter an issue with the jabra project on github with regards to the chrome extn they provide as not working.